# PHP MYSQL Prevent duplicate results in frontend from the database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i am using `CodeIgniter` and i have a problem with duplicated name.

**This is my `Model`:**

```
function displayCategory($id){
    $this->db->distinct();
    $this->db->select('category');
    $this->db->where('avenu_id',$id);
    $result = $this->db->get('personal_closest')->result_array();
    return $result;
}
```

**This is my `Controller`:**

```
$shop['category'] = $this->personal_closest->displayAvenuCategory($id);
```

**And this is the `View`:**

```
<ul class="tag-list">
    <?php foreach ($avenuadmin as $key => $value) { ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url().'social/category/'.$value['category']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-tag"></i> <?php echo $value['category']; ?></a></li>
     <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

I am using `distinct()` function to prevent duplicate but is not working and my output is:

> ACCESSORIES, HOME, TECH, WHATCHES, TECH, TECH.
>   I need to show just ACCESSORIES, HOME, TECH, WHATCHES.

Comment: You show a Model with the method called displayCategory. Your Controller code snippet shows you are calling displayAvenueCategory to load a variable called $category and your View is using a variable called $avenueadmin. What is the real,actual situation?

Comment: As you can see the problem was in the View i was calling the wrong variable $avenuadmin instead $category ._.°

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distinct will not always work.

You should add ->

```
$this->db->distinct();
$this->db->group_by('column_name');
```

**OR**

```
$this->db->select('DISTINCT `name`'); 
$this->db->select('*');
```

In Controller

```
$data['category'] = $this->personal_closest->displayAvenuCategory($id);
$this->load->view('view_file_name', $data);
```

In View use

```
$category
```

to access the details.

Comment: Same problem doesn't change nothing :(

Comment: Updated the answer, use group_by after distinct. Hope it helps.

Comment: Is not working, if i use distinct(); and grou_by(); i got the same output

Comment: where this $avenuadmin array come. submit your full code

Comment: If you have used ->   $shop['category'] = $this->personal_closest->displayAvenuCategory($id);  Then the view variable should be $category.

Comment: Thanks tiGer the problem was this one! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function displayCategory($id){
    // $this->db->distinct();
    $this->db->select('category');
    $this->db->where('avenu_id',$id);
    $this->db->group_by('category'); // group by category name
    $result = $this->db->get('personal_closest')->result_array();
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have make a var_dump to the $shop['category']; and that's the results:

```
  array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["category"]=>
    string(3) "CAP"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["category"]=>
    string(4) "HOME"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["category"]=>
    string(4) "TECH"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    ["category"]=>
    string(8) "WHATCHES"
  }
}
```

Comment: Then what is the problem . your array show category are distinct??

Comment: The problem is in the view i got duplicates.

Comment: Yes, the records are distinct here.

Comment: How that can be possible if you are using the right variable in view. Please check your variable.